# How do I prevent my wordpress site from automatically zooming in when using mobile devices?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a website right now, it's tiniglesias.com ... and everytime I try to use my iphone to check it, it is automatically zooming in.

I've already deactivated all of my plugins to check if any of it is causing this to happen, but it is still zooming in.

I've also tried using the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Still not working.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Update:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Your site is not optimized for mobiles it seems. You should focus on providing some styles for mobile platforms.

Comment: Hi! I am still not ready to optimize the site for mobile as of now since it's still not needed hehehe